# org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Illegal type (de.db.kigbau.client.domain.Benutzer) to deserialize: prevented for security reasons

Tags: java, angular, jackson

When sending the POST request from my angular client to my Rest API, I am getting the above error.

below is my request model coming from angular client:

```
{
   "anmeldename":"KBBT765",
   "nachname":"nach",
   "vorname":"vor",
   "telefonnummer":"4563",
   "password":"szpi;ItM",
   "rolle":"B",
   "region":"Z",
   "eiuname":"",
   "zbname":"",
   "evuname":"",
   "spnv":false,
   "spfv":false,
   "sgv":false,
   "fromEdit":false
}
```

Below is the rest API POST method to handle the request from angular client and parse the json fields to Benutzer Model:

```java
@POST
        @Path("speichern")

        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

        public boolean speichern(Benutzer benutzerInfo) { 

--------------
---------------
}
```

Rest API Benutzer Model is below:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Benutzer implements Serializable {

    private String nachname;
    private String anmeldename;
    private String vorname;
    private String rolle;
    private String region;
    private String eiuname;
    private String zbname;
    private String evuname;
    private String password;
    private String telefonnummer;
    private String defaultAnmeldname;

    private Boolean spnv;
    private Boolean spfv;
    private Boolean sgv;
    private Boolean fromEdit;

    @JsonProperty("evuProfilelist")
    private List<EvuProfilSelectedItem> evuProfilelist;

    public void setRolle(String rolle) {
        this.rolle = rolle;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public void setEiuname(String eiuname) {
        this.eiuname = eiuname;
    }

    public void setZbname(String zbname) {
        this.zbname = zbname;
    }

    public void setEvuname(String evuname) {
        this.evuname = evuname;
    }

    public void setSpnv(Boolean spnv) {
        this.spnv = spnv;
    }

    public void setSpfv(Boolean spfv) {
        this.spfv = spfv;
    }

    public void setSgv(Boolean sgv) {
        this.sgv = sgv;
    }

    public String getRolle() {
        return rolle;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public String getEiuname() {
        return eiuname;
    }

    public String getZbname() {
        return zbname;
    }

    public String getEvuname() {
        return evuname;
    }

    public Boolean isSpnv() {
        return spnv;
    }

    public Boolean isSpfv() {
        return spfv;
    }

    public Boolean isSgv() {
        return sgv;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<EvuProfilSelectedItem> getEvuProfilelist() {
        return evuProfilelist;
    }

    public void setEvuProfilelist(List<EvuProfilSelectedItem> evuProfilelist) {
        this.evuProfilelist = evuProfilelist;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getTelefonnummer() {
        return telefonnummer;
    }

    public void setTelefonnummer(String telefonnummer) {
        this.telefonnummer = telefonnummer;
    }

    public String getNachname() {
        return nachname;
    }

    public void setNachname(String nachname) {
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }

    public String getAnmeldename() {
        return anmeldename;
    }

    public void setAnmeldename(String anmeldename) {
        this.anmeldename = anmeldename;
    }

    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }

    public void setVorname(String vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }

    public Boolean isFromEdit() {
        return fromEdit;
    }

    public void setFromEdit(Boolean fromEdit) {
        this.fromEdit = fromEdit;
    }

    public String getDefaultAnmeldname() {
        return defaultAnmeldname;
    }

    public void setDefaultAnmeldname(String defaultAnmeldname) {
        this.defaultAnmeldname = defaultAnmeldname;
    }

}
```

Stack Trace:

2020-03-05 06:42:57,017|ERROR|http-0.0.0.0:17206-4|kigbau.client.RestExceptionMapper||(Request-ID: 9fdG4mDBJWUqtjnqWhdx32) Propagating Exception to the client||| org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Illegal type (de.db.kigbau.client.domain.Benutzer) to deserialize: prevented for security reasons at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.checkLegalTypes(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:1536) at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:668)

Is this due to blank or null values in the fields coming from angular client or some thing else?

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this relevant? [JBEAP-14760](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBEAP-14760)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What versions of Jackson are allowed in JBoss 6.4.20 patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50917932/5221149)

Comment: Show full stacktrace!!!

Comment: 2020-03-05 06:42:57,017|ERROR|http-0.0.0.0:17206-4|kigbau.client.RestExceptionMapper||(Request-ID: 9fdG4mDBJWUqtjnqWhdx32) Propagating Exception to the client|||
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Illegal type (de.db.kigbau.client.domain.Benutzer) to deserialize: prevented for security reasons
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.checkLegalTypes(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:1536)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:668)

Comment: @user5281762 It would be much more readable if you update the question with your stacktrace rtaher than comment

Comment: Don't know what version of Jackson you're running with, because I can't find source code for `BeanDeserializerFactory` that has at least 1536 lines, or a `checkLegalTypes` method, so it's rather difficult to figure out what exactly would cause that particular error message.

Comment: So this error is related to code or some jboss configuration?